# How do you auto-populate the email address on a feedback form in IOS?

Tags: iphone, email, email-address, auto-populate

Wakemate does an amazing job of auto-populating a users email address in a Feedback form in an iphone app. See here:

Does anyone know how to do this (with the caveat that we are using Facebook Connect for login)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you should read [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)
it will help you and more over the ui that is being used here is just because they probably subclassed MFMailComposeViewController

Comment: Thanks Inder! I had already read that and we prepared that. However, I think it's more natural for the user to see the form and type into it. I don't want to take them away from the App. We may never get them back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this block of code  for your purpose.

```
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"abcd@xyz.com"];
NSString *tosubject =txtSubject.text;
[picker setSubject:tosubject];


// Set up recipients
[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
```

Cheers